# WordPress RSS feed to external XML

Tags: htaccess, rss

I have generated my RSS XML feed from fetchrss.com. I want to display those RSS data for my WP site.

How should I do this? Is this possible.

What I am planning to do is .. to redirect the www.example.com/feed/ to my external URL using .htaccess.
Will this work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work. Keep in mind, however, that in this way you are only catching the main feed. WordPress generates a lot of other feeds, for instance per category.